# Azure SAML Passing Claim for user.assignedroles to Zoom

Tags: azure, zooming, saml

Connecting to the Zoom gallery app works for authentication and most of the basic claims are being passed but Azure is failing to send user.assignedroles even though it's defined and set as an attribute for users.

I'm not sure what I'm missing if anything to get Azure to pass this attribute.

[Azure Claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/des3i.jpg)